# Can you leave at a connecting airport and miss the leg to the destination?

Tags: uk

I've booked a flight for my daughter from New York to Dublin via Heathrow. She works in the UK. We are changing planes in Heathrow; can she just get off and leave the airport in London, instead of flying to Dublin only to to fly back to Heathrow?

Comment: [Short read which should clear up the most used schemes to get around ticketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys). Short answer: yes, but she must fly without check-in baggage.